# Can't assembly scala/akka project

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-stream

I'm newby with sbt and scala. Just want to make jar file to run in on server, but when I try to compile jar file I get error. Program code is very simple, only one class (can't post it here, stackoverflow doesn't allow). When I run it in Intellij everything is fine. But sbt assembly fires this error:

```
[info] Merging files...
[error] scala.MatchError: akka\stream\OverflowStrategies$.class (of class java.lang.String)
[error]         at $a019333dc409d47a4d92$.$anonfun$$sbtdef$2(D:\workspace_scala\TestSbt2\build.sbt:25)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.$anonfun$applyStrategies$6(Assembly.scala:115)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:114)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:26)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:68)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:58)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:85)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.$anonfun$assemblyTask$1(Assembly.scala:249)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (assembly) scala.MatchError: akka\stream\OverflowStrategies$.class (of class java.lang.String)
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 20, 2018 1:20:02 PM
```

built.sbt

```
name := "TestSbt2"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.13"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.13"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.0"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
}
```

project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

Program code:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.http.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{Message, TextMessage}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import scala.io.StdIn

object Server2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    def echoFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
      Flow[Message].map {
        case tm: TextMessage.Strict => TextMessage.Strict("Test " + tm.text)
        case _ => TextMessage("Message type unsupported")
      }

    val websocketRoute =
      path("chat") {
        handleWebSocketMessages(echoFlow)
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(websocketRoute, "127.0.0.1", 8080)

    // the rest of the sample code will go here
    println("- Started server at 127.0.0.1:8080, press enter to kill server")
    StdIn.readLine()
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using all three dependencies in your project, might be because of version conflicts, if not try to change the merge strategy to first or last or which ever  is working.

Comment: Tried to change merge strategy to last/first/concat - nothing. Seems like I'm the lucky one, really close to give up with scala :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what's going on, but if you add a `default` case to your `assemblyMergeStrategy` definition, it should work just fine.

For example:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Little edit:

Actually on the repo it says

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly expects a function. You can't do assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := MergeStrategy.first
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it says "MatchError", it's found in the build.sbt file and your sbt file says

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
}
```

tells me, that you want to use a fallback case.

Add this as a second case in the same match (after your `case PathList`)

```
case x =>
  val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
  oldStrategy(x)
```

(copied from [GitHub-sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people!

This helped:

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("chat.Server2")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```